# Downsample large .tif images while reading

Tags: python, image, image-processing, tiff

I am working with hundreds of large high resolution .tif images that are very memory intensive to read in Python. Fortunately, I can often work with low resolution versions of these images by downsampling them after loading them. I am wondering if there is a way to only read part of the image into memory instead of the whole image to improve read speed.

The code below shows an example of what I would like, however, this still reads the whole image into memory before returning the downsampled array. Is it possible to only read every nth pixel values into memory to improve read speed?

```
from tifffile import imread

def standardOpen(f):
    im = imread(f)
    return(im)

def scaledOpen(f):
    im = imread(f)[::,::4,::4]
    return(im)

f_path = '/file_name.tif'

im = standardOpen(f_path)
print(im.shape)
>>(88, 2048, 2048)

im_scaled = scaledOpen(f_path)
print(im_scaled.shape)
>>(88, 512, 512)
```

EDIT: I have uploaded a sample image to dropbox: https://www.dropbox.com/s/xkm0bzudcv2sw5d/S000_t000002_V000_R0000_X000_Y000_C02_I1_D0_P00101.tif?dl=0

This image is 101 slice of 2048x2048 pixels. When I read it using tifffile.imread(image_path) I get a numpy array of shape (101, 2048, 2048)

Comment: Try the [zarr interface to read parts of the image data](https://github.com/cgohlke/tifffile/blob/891a61f2474f795e29e0c439dc878a06ca5f0b70/tifffile/tifffile.py#L583-L594). Whether that's efficient depends on how the image data is stored in the file.

Comment: Reading every nth pixel has a catastrophic effect on the image quality (aliasing). To reduce in size, you first have to apply a lowpass filter, which necessitates all pixels. Did you measure the loading time of an image ?

Comment: You might consider making pyramidal TIFFs, so you can select your desired resolution... https://www.libvips.org/API/current/Making-image-pyramids.md.html

Comment: You might consider sharing one using Dropbox or Google Drive so that folks can get an idea of what you are dealing with...

Comment: @MarkSetchell it looks to me like the `image` tag is totally appropriate. `vips` may be relevant to the answer but not the question.

Comment: @MarkRansom Agreed - although I wasn't actually suggesting `image` was not appropriate. My thought process was that the `image` tag is often (mis-)used for *"disk images"*, *"backup system images"* and *"Docker images"*, and all the folks likely to answer questions about images - as in *"pictures/photos"* - follow the `image-processing` tag anyway, so the `vips` tag might garner a wider audience and hopefully a better answer than the near-useless IMHO `image` tag. I will delete my earlier suggestion though

Comment: Thank you @cgohlke for the `zarr` suggestion. This results in an marginal increase in read speed relative to simply using imread.

Comment: I don't know anything about making pyrimidal TIFFs @MarkSetchell but I will check it out and thank you for the suggestion. Per your other suggestion I have also edited the original post to include a link to a sample file on Dropbox (https://www.dropbox.com/s/xkm0bzudcv2sw5d/S000_t000002_V000_R0000_X000_Y000_C02_I1_D0_P00101.tif?dl=0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sample file, `S000_t000002_V000_R0000_X000_Y000_C02_I1_D0_P00101.tif`, is a multi-page TIFF. The image data in each page is stored uncompressed in one strip. To speed up reading sliced data from this specific kind of TIFF file, memory-map the frame data and copy the sliced data to a pre-allocated array while iterating over the pages in the file. Unless one wants to preserve noise characteristics, it is usually better to downsample using higher order filtering, e.g interpolation using OpenCV:

```
import numpy
import tifffile
import cv2  # OpenCV for fast interpolation

filename = 'S000_t000002_V000_R0000_X000_Y000_C02_I1_D0_P00101.tif'

with tifffile.Timer():
    stack = tifffile.imread(filename)[:, ::4, ::4].copy()

with tifffile.Timer():
    with tifffile.TiffFile(filename) as tif:
        page = tif.pages[0]
        shape = len(tif.pages), page.imagelength // 4, page.imagewidth // 4
        stack = numpy.empty(shape, page.dtype)
        for i, page in enumerate(tif.pages):
            stack[i] = page.asarray(out='memmap')[::4, ::4]
            # # better use interpolation instead:
            # stack[i] = cv2.resize(
            #     page.asarray(),
            #     dsize=(shape[2], shape[1]),
            #     interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR,
            # )
```

I would avoid this kind of micro-optimization for little speed gain. The image data in the sample file is only ~800 MB and easily fits into RAM on most computers.

Comment: Big thanks, this is perfect. I realize we're over engineering for a single file, but I'll be opening up hundreds/thousands of these at a time and so any improvement in read speed will be noticeable. One quick follow up if you don't mind - on my machine it takes ~40 ms to open the file with `imread`, ~230 ms to read by file page with `page.asarray(out='memmap')[::4, ::4]` and ~20 ms to read by file page with `page.asarray()[::4, ::4]` that is, it's faster to exclude `out=memmap'. I don't really understand the pros/cons of memmap, do you have any references to read up on this approach?

Answer (score 1):

I did some experiments with [pyvips](https://pypi.org/project/pyvips/) to simulate your workflow.

To get started, I created a 6.7GB TIF with dimensions 60,000 x 40,000 pixels. Then I loaded it with `pyvips` and shrank it to fit within a 1,000 x 1,000 rectangle and saved the result:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import pyvips

# Resize to no more than 1000x1000 pixels
out = pyvips.Image.thumbnail('big.tif', 1000)

# Save with LZW compression
out.tiffsave('result.tif', tile=True, compression='lzw')
```

That took 3 seconds and used 440MB of RAM - including the Python interpreter. You can then make that into a regular Numpy array like this - it is actually just one line of code - there is just some mapping:

```
# map vips formats to np dtypes
format_to_dtype = {
   'uchar': np.uint8,
   'char': np.int8,
   'ushort': np.uint16,
   'short': np.int16,
   'uint': np.uint32,
   'int': np.int32,
   'float': np.float32,
   'double': np.float64,
   'complex': np.complex64,
   'dpcomplex': np.complex128,
}

# vips image to numpy array
def vips2numpy(vi):
    return np.ndarray(buffer=vi.write_to_memory(),
                  dtype=format_to_dtype[vi.format],
                  shape=[vi.height, vi.width, vi.bands])

# Do actual conversion from vips image to Numpy array
na = vips2numpy(out)
```

---

You can do the same in Terminal, with [vipsthumbnail](https://www.libvips.org/API/current/Using-vipsthumbnail.md.html) by the way:

```
vipsthumbnail big.tif result.tif --size=1000 --vips-leak
memory: high-water mark 372.78 MB
```

Comment: `pyvips` looks very cool, I use a pipeline approach in my own code.

Comment: @MarkRansom Yes, and John (the author) is very responsive with assistance too.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion! `pyvips` seems like a promising approach. Unfortunately the thumbnail suggestion is not as fast as `imread(f)[::,::4,::4]` and after array mapping results in an array of shape (512, 512, 1) instead of (101, 512, 512) using the sample image that I just uploaded to Dropbox (see edit in initial post).

Answer (score 0):

Your sample image is 100 pages, and each page is a 2048 x 2048 pixel 16-bit greyscale image encoded as a single, uncompressed strip.

With pyvips, you'd need to load all the pages as a long, vertical strip, chop into pages, resize each page, then write back again I guess as another TIFF. Perhaps:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import pyvips

# scan the image as a single huge vertical strip
image = pyvips.Image.new_from_file(sys.argv[1], n=-1)

# cut into an array of pages
page_height = image.get("page-height")
pages = [image.crop(0, y, image.width, page_height)
         for y in range(0, image.height, page_height)]

# size each page down to 512x512
pages = [page.resize(0.25, kernel="linear") for page in pages]

# join back into a huge vertical strip again
image = pyvips.Image.arrayjoin(pages, across=1)
image.set("page-height", page_height / 4)

image.write_to_file(sys.argv[2])
```

I see:

```
$ /usr/bin/time -f %M:%e ./zac.py ~/pics/S000_t000002_V000_R0000_X000_Y000_C02_I1_D0_P00101.tif x.tif
134628:1.49
```

So 130mb of RAM and 1.5s of runtime. That's writing another 100 page, 16-bit uncompressed TIFF, but with each page now 512x512. `kernel="linear"` means linear interpolation for the downsample, so there shouldn't be too much aliasing.

As @cgohike says, mapping the file and reading out the pixel values directly would be a lot quicker.